# Need help converting this inline javascript to a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML/JS that shows an initial value, removes it when you click in the input field, and then re-populates it with the original value if you don't enter anything.

I need to do this on multiple input fields on the same page and thus would like to turn it into a jQuery function that I could then apply to any input field with a certain class.

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="Search by name" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search by name') {this.value = '';this.style.color = '#000';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search by name';this.style.color = '#aaa';}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make your life easier and give the input a class:

```
<input type="text" class="search" name="search">
```

You can use an attribute selector:

```
$(":text[name='search']")...
```

but this is *much* faster:

```
$("input.search")...
```

and then use this:

```
$(function() {
  $("input.search").focus(function() {
    this.defaultval = this.defaultval || $(this).val();
    if ($(this).val() == this.defaultval) {
      $(this).val("").css("color", "#000");
    }
  }).blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).val(this.defaultval).css("color", "#AAA");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: "a jQuery function that I could then apply to any input field with a certain class."

Comment: That is, your solution isn't quite as general as what the OP was asking for.

Comment: It's still not very general since it assumes "Search by name" is a constant.

Comment: How do I make this work with multiple form fields? What would be nice is if it grabbed the contents of the `value` attribute so I can use it with any/multiple input fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(":text[name='search']")
  .focus(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'Search by name')
      $(this).val("").css("color", "black");
  })
  .blur(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "")
      $(this).val("Search by name").css("color", "#aaa");
  });
```

Comment: How do I make this work with multiple form fields? What would be nice is if it grabbed the contents of the `value` attribute so I can use it with any/multiple input fields.

Comment: You can apply this to any number of fields by changing the selector, and making it more broad. I'm not sure what you mean by grabbing the value though.

Answer (score 0):

untested

```
jQuery(function () {
jQuery("input[type=text]").bind("focus",function(e){
   var input = e.target;
   input.defaultval = input.defaultval || input.value;
   if(input.value==input.defaultval) {
       input.value = "";
       input.style.color = '#000';

   }
}).bind("blur",function(e){
      var input = e.target;
      if(input.value == '') {
         input.value = input.defaultval;
         input.style.color = '#aaa';
      }
})

});
```

edit: this seems to be a more general solution than the others. It takes as default text whatever happens to be in the input field first. Though I don't bother wrapping the event target in a jquery to alter the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a plugin

```
$.fn.inputMagic=function(text){
  return this.each(function(){
    var text=$(this).val()||text||''
    $(this).focus(function(){
     if ($(this).val() == text){
       $(this).val("").css("color", "black");
     }
    }).blur(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == ""){
       $(this).val(text).css("color", "#aaa");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
$('input.search').inputMagic('Search by name').show();//and continue to chain
```

Comment: How do I make this work with multiple form fields? What would be nice is if it grabbed the contents of the `value` attribute so I can use it with any/multiple input fields.

Comment: I modified the code to capture the value of the field as its default. (Line 3)